# PHP images not saving to folder but uploads to database

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to make it where a user can upload an image to their profile and I have been watching YouTube videos for tutorials and this is the closest I have at getting what I am looking for but the problem is that my images won't save to the folder I want them stored in but uploads the file name to phpmyadmin with no problem. The original code is [here](https://codewithawa.com/posts/image-upload-using-php-and-mysql-database).

```
<?php
  // Create database connection
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");

  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

    // image file directory
    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Upload</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #content{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   form{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
   }
   form div{
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   #img_div{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   #img_div:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
   }
   img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
        echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
  <form method="POST" action="music.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea
        id="text"
        cols="40"
        rows="4"
        name="image_text"
        placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your database related code does not error checking at all. If something fails you will not be reported, let alone get diagnostics.

Comment: Probably a simple error, add debugging to the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your upload folder permission it has read write access or not.

Comment: Wow. All that for something so simple. Thank you. It works perfectly now.